# Cannot create Blob Container locally using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to create Locally Blob Container using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. I keep getting error as show in the image. I am using (Emulator - Default Ports) (Key) -> Blob Containers. I am using 1.12 version. The name I want to called is countries. Emulator version no 5.10

[image]

Comment: What version of Storage Emulator you’re using? What’s the name of the blob container you’re trying to create?

Comment: I am using 1.12 version. The name I want to called is countries.

Comment: Sorry, but one more thing: What's the version of Storage Emulator you're running?

Comment: Emulator version no 5.10

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce your issue, it should work, I use the explorer and the emulator with the same version as yours, it works fine.

Please try to uninstall and install them again, download explorer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) and emulator in [Command-line tools](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/), and make sure you open the storage explorer after the emulator started successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @maxspan Try to Initialize the storage emulator, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#initialize-the-storage-emulator-to-use-a-different-sql-database).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was run Emulator and type the below command.

**AzureStorageEmulator init /server . -skipcreate**

the above command skips the creation of local database and now it works.